# Will PHP work on Oracle OAS by default?

Tags: php, oracle, oas

I am not entirely sure whether this question should be asked here or the SuperUser forum, but I was wondering if Oracle Application Server is capable of running PHP scripts by default. I can't seem to find anything on the internet saying either way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this will clear

> PHP is a supported as a mod (mod_php) with the Oracle HTTP Server. The version shipped with Oracle Application Server 10g Release 3 (10.1.3.1.0) is PHP 5.1.2.

from [oracle doc 1.6 point](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/ohs-101310-faq-131717.pdf)

> Oracle includes PHP with its mid-tier Application Server 10g Release 3 allowing you to use the same web server for PHP and for J2EE applications.
>
> PHP is enabled by default. The Oracle `HTTP` Server document root is
>
> `$ORACLE_HOME/Apache/Apache/htdocs`
>   Files with ***.php*** or ***.phtml*** extensions in this directory will be executed by *PHP*. Files with a .phps extension will be displayed as formatted source code.
>
> above quoted from [Oracle:PHP and Oracle](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/entry/upgrade_php_with_oracle_applic)